# Error while writing to BigTable using cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, treemap

I'm getting the following error while writing a large number of records to BigTable.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:347)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.logRetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException(AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.java:58)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.logExceptions(AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableIO$BufferedMutatorDoFn$1.onException(CloudBigtableIO.java:840)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.handleExceptions(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:146)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutator.mutate(BigtableBufferedMutator.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.beam.CloudBigtableIO$CloudBigtableSingleTableBufferedWriteFn.processElement(CloudBigtableIO.java:877)
```

I think it has something to do with the implementation of the TreeMap class. This only happens when I increase the number of records that are read from GCS.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you perhaps post your code?